# Routing with optional values and default value

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

i am trying to implement a route with an optional value (language) and if it is not given by url, a default value for it, for example "de".

i have following test-controllers:

```
public IActionResult Index(string lang = "de")
{
    return View();
}

public IActionResult Privacy(string lang = "de")
{
    return View();
}
```

and following router configuration:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{lang?}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

so my expected result should be:

```
path:                                expected invocation:                    actual invocation
localhost:44305/                 --> invoke Index(string lang = "de")    --> working
locahlhost:44305/home/en/index   --> invoke Index(string lang = "en")    --> working
localhost:44305/home/privacy     --> invoke Privcay(string lang = "de")  --> ERROR!!! invoking Index(string lang = "privacy") 
localhost:44305/home/de/privacy  --> invoke Privacy(string lang = "de")  --> working
localhost:44305/home/en/privacy  --> invoke Privacy(string lang = "en")  --> working
```

As you can see, i got the problem with the url ../home/privacy, cause the controller thinks, its my new language string.

Are there any suggestions how i can prevent it?

Comment: Sry, didn't know i can do that. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route template like below:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "lang",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{lang?}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir! That is what i was searching for.